# Javascript: Chrome dev tools OR NetBeans?

Tags: java, maven, google-chrome, tomcat, netbeans

When I deploy Java Web Application on Tomcat server with Maven, I don't know how to write JS in realtime without redeploy. If I create and save JS in Chrome Dev Tools I have to redeploy my application every time.

If I use NetBeans for JS development, it puts changed files in /target folder . Which is used by tomcat. I would develop in NetBeans if it had JS console (but I didn't find JS console).

What should I do? How do people develop and debug in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use both NetBeans and Chrome dev tools in conjunction. Make your changes in NetBeans with hot deploy but use Chrome dev tools for debugging, placing breakpoints etc.

You might also find this useful: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/143453/best-way-of-javascript-web-development-in-netbeans-hot-deployment

Comment: Thank you. I've read your link and decided to use Mozilla with Firebug!

Answer (score 1):

The latest (8.x) Netbeans have a plugin for Chrome(ium). You can then use breakpoints from your IDE and have the browser console output in your IDE as well.
While it has some shortcommings compared to the chrome dev tools it provides a very good developer experience due to the good integration. You should really give it a try.